# Kosher butter substitute for baking (flavour and mouthfeel)

Tags: substitutions, butter, kosher

I'm looking to find a pareve (non-dairy, non-meat) substitute for butter which lends a similar flavour and mouthfeel for baking. I would be using it to make something along the lines of a brioche (French, not the so-called American version).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The classic substitute is [**margarine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine).

Most brands are vegan, which would meet your non-dairy /non-meat requirements.

As far as taste and mouthfeel goes, I suggest either trying out a few brands or checking some vegan blogs *from your country or region*, there is a difference between brands but some are reported to be remarkably close - whatever that means.

Comment: The problem is that most margarines with which I have experience don't lend the same mouthfeel and have significantly different flavours from butter (understandably)

Comment: No problem, pareve-certified margarine options (many have dairy certification, if you can believe it) are few and far between in my area (near Boston, MA)

Comment: @NoahM yes, margarines taste differently. However, they are the best try by decades of food science to replicate the taste of butter. If there is a way to get closer to butter taste, humanity has not found it yet.

Comment: @NoahM I think many have butter/milk derivatives in them to "improve" the flavour, while keeping the (saturated) fat down. Also I'm no expert - not by a long shot - but if a process line was used for a dairy product could it then make a dairy-free product under kosher rules?